# How to persist cart in UberCart?

Tags: session, drupal-7, ubercart

I have a cart to which I add Products A and B. Product A can be bought without B, but if you buy Product A, you must buy Product B as well. I wrote a simple table to keep track of these relationships and stops you from checking out when they rules are broken.

My problem comes in when a user add to their cart and then proceeds to register. After registration the cart_item_id has changed and the user's session_id has changed.

How can I match up the session from the anonymous user with the session of the now registered and logged in user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a second table for the data I wanted to persist, I realised I could just add any data to the cartContents and it will automatically keep all the information i store when the user logs in and out.

This is how I did the update:

```
$cartItemID = 1; // the id of the item in the cart I want to add info to
$cartContents = uc_cart_get_contents();
foreach ($cartContents as $c) 
{
    if ($c->cart_item_id == $cartItemID)
    {
        $c->data['my_chosen_key'] = $sessionData;
        uc_cart_update_item($c);
    }
}
```

Information stays if you log out and back in.